# Dropbox won't download all the files to my PC

Tags: dropbox, sync

I have a problem with my Dropbox account. I have about a thousand photographs/videos on my Dropbox account (online), and I have my account linked to my PC. However, it only downloads half of the photographs online. To answer some questions:

- Yes, I have enough space on my PC;
- No, I don't have selective syncing on;
- Yes, I have reinstalled Dropbox several times.

I have also tried to share the folder (camera uploads) with a family member to see if they can access all the photographs/videos on their PC, but when they download it, it only downloads the same 500 pictures as on my PC. Dropbox has a download option, which I have tried, but it downloads a file with the name 'unspecified' which can't be opened. Furthermore, I *can* download the photographs individually from the website, but that would take a very long time. Does anyone know what's wrong? I've tried this on Windows 10 and Windows 7.

Comment: The question [Can't download folder from Dropbox](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89932/cant-download-folder-from-dropbox) relates to your "downloads a file with the name 'unspecified'" problem. However, I didn't think this same restriction applied to the Dropbox app installed on the PC? Also, if you are over your storage quota it will fail to sync: https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/5

Comment: What is the size of the folder you're trying to download and how many files are inside?

Answer (score 0):

> It's not possible to use dropbox.com to download an entire folder
>   that's over 1 GB or that has over 10,000 files.

https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/49

Answer (score 0):

Have you worked throught https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/8840 this help page? Specifically I'm wondering about step 2:

> Verify that your files are not synced.
>
> Files with a red X are not synced; files with a circular blue arrow
>   are in the process of syncing, and files with a green check mark
>   should be fully synced Note: The icons that can appear on individual
>   files in your Dropbox are different than the icons that tell you about
>   the current state of Dropbox itself. Learn more about the different
>   icons that can appear on your files.

Navigate to the dropbox folder using windows explorer and look at the icons on the missing files if any.